# How to clear the data of a LiveData Object after a Success response in Retrofit Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, retrofit2, android-livedata

I created a request inside a viewModel for adding a new Contact, and I use a LiveData object to store the data from the response to check different things inside my Fragment. My problem is, how can I clear the object after adding a contact? After adding a new contact successfully, when I press the Add Button again even if I don't fill any field, the success function in my fragment is called. I think this is because of the last item added so I need to clear the data. Is that possible? Thanks.

ViewModel class:

```
val contactNew: LiveData<Resource<UserModel>>
    get() = _contactNew
private val _contactNew = MutableLiveData<Resource<UserModel>>()

 fun addNewContact(
    phoneNumber: String,
    username: String,
    firstName: String,
    lastName: String,
    email: String,
    birthdate: String,
    otherEvent: String,
    eventDate: String
) {
    var addedContact = UserModel(
        username = username,
        phone = phoneNumber,
        firstName = firstName,
        lastName = lastName,
        email = email,
        birthday = birthdate,
        eventTitle = otherEvent,
        eventDate = eventDate
    )

    _isLoading.value = true

    disposable.add(
        contactsAndGroupsRepository.postAddContact(
            handlerId = SharedPreferencesHelper.handlerId,
            contactNew = addedContact
        )
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribeWith(object : DisposableSingleObserver<UserModel>() {
                override fun onSuccess(response: UserModel) {
                    _isLoading.value = false
                    _contactNew.value = Resource.success(response)
                    Log.e(TAG, response.id)
                }

                override fun onError(e: Throwable) {
                    _isLoading.value = false
                    _contactNew.value = Resource.error(e.message)
                    Log.e(TAG, e.message.toString())
                }
            }
            )
    )
}
```

**AddContactFragment**

```
 override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
    if (item.itemId == R.id.add_contact_action) {
        activity?.hideKeyboard()
        addContact()
        observeAddContactResponse()
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
}

private fun addContact() {
    viewModel.isLoading.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, {
        binding.isLoading = it ?: true
    })
    val phoneNumber = binding.countryCodePicker.fullNumberWithPlus.trim()
    val username = binding.username.text!!.trim().toString()
    val firstName = binding.firstName.text!!.trim().toString()
    val lastName = binding.lastName.text!!.trim().toString()
    val email = binding.emailAddress.text!!.trim().toString()
    val birthdate = formatDate(binding.birthdate.text!!.trim().toString())
    val otherEvent = binding.eventTitle.text!!.trim().toString()
    val eventDate = formatDate(binding.eventDate.text!!.trim().toString())
    if (binding.phoneNumber.text!!.isNotEmpty() && username.isNotEmpty() && firstName.isNotEmpty() && lastName.isNotEmpty()) {
        if (isPhoneNumberValid(
                binding.countryCodePicker.fullNumberWithPlus,
                binding.countryCodePicker.selectedCountryCode
            )
        ) {
            if (email.isNullOrEmpty() || Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email).matches()) {
                if ((birthdate.isNullOrEmpty()) || (birthdayInMilliseconds < Calendar.getInstance().timeInMillis)) {
                    viewModel.addNewContact(
                        phoneNumber,
                        username,
                        firstName,
                        lastName,
                        email,
                        birthdate,
                        otherEvent,
                        eventDate
                    )

                } else {
                    showDialog(R.string.something_wrong, R.string.invalid_date)
                }
            } else
                showDialog(R.string.something_wrong, R.string.invalid_email)
        } else {
            showDialog(R.string.something_wrong, R.string.invalid_phone_number)
        }
    } else {
        this.showToast(resources.getString(R.string.fill_required_info), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
    }
}

private fun observeAddContactResponse() {
    viewModel.contactNew.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, {  contactNew ->
        contactNew?.let {
            if (it.status == Status.SUCCESS) {
                binding.setPictureButton.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                hideMenu()
                showDialog(R.string.success, R.string.contact_added_successfully)
            } else {
                if (it.message!!.contains("409")) {
                   if (!isDialogShown) {
                        isDialogShown = true
                        showDialog(R.string.something_wrong, R.string.contact_exists)
                    }
                } else
                    if (!isDialogShown) {
                        isDialogShown = true
                        showDialog(R.string.something_wrong, R.string.something_wrong_message)
                    }
            }
        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you call `observeAddContactResponse()` after `addContact()` with checking whether its valid or not , then in `observeAddContactResponse()` you checked if the call to the server response will be successful or not , and its seem to be successful here , what lead to act as if its was a valid data , what you should do is to call `observeAddContactResponse()` within last if statement in `addContact()` .

Answer (score 0):

Just remove `observeAddContactResponse` from `onOptionsItemSelected` and replace it in `onCreate`
This is happening because you set an Observer for `contactNew` each time you trigger the addButton